# How can I return two data coming from different pages?

Tags: php, get, return

I am returning a id variable with get function on a link to new page. I need to return a new variable to same page. But I cant do this with link method.

Here's index.php.

```
echo '<td align="center">'.$row[0].'-)&nbsp;<a href="records.php?mid=' . $row[0] . '"$ >'.  $row[3] . "&nbsp;" . $row[4] .'</a></td>';
```

I'm returning 'mid' to records.php.

records.php

```
    if (isset($_GET['mid']))
{
    $id = $_GET['mid'];
}

?>
```

I want to use new data variable coming from 'other.php' in 'records.php'.

Here is other.php.

```
echo '<td align="center">'.$row[0].'-)&nbsp;<a href="records.php?id=' . $row[0] . '"$ >'.  $row[3] . "&nbsp;" . $row[4] .'</a></td>';
```

But my first link changed now, I can't arrive it. Which way should I use?

Comment: Put `mid` and `id` in one link?

Comment: Maybe, i dont know that s my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to read in records.php two parameters: mid from index.php and id from other.php

You want to click link in index.php and next link in other.php and read both parameters in records.php?

If yes that is not possible this way.
If both index.php and other.php are pointing to same records.php file you have to firstly check if that parameter exist in $_GET, and if it exist save it to session or global variable, file, cookie, etc. I recommend to use session then.

Then you can add additional condition to check if both variables exist in session and then proceed with them.

Anyway, more info about this what you want to do will tell us more, looks like you are doing something that could be done easier...

Comment: Yes you understood.I see, can say something more.I want use - mid from index.php - id from other.php in a records.php. Somebady said me create a newrecords.php after send two id in a link with '&' arithmetic sign. Like 'localhost/newrecords.php?mid=6&id=5'

Comment: If you will use 'localhost/newrecords.php?mid=6&id=5' you will have both parameters, but it could be done only by single link.

Comment: small update:
If you will use 'localhost/newrecords.php?mid=6&id=5' you will have both parameters, but it could be done only by single link.
You can do this tht way if your first link on page index.php will redirect you to other.php where you will read mid parameter and add it to link which will redirect you to records.php where you can readu then both parameters.

But if both link you need must redirect to records.php then you coud use session to save that data first. Then just read how to use $_SESSION

Comment: Can I use only sessions for save first data?

Comment: $_SESSION['abc'] = $variable;
Thats all. Then you can read that anywhere until session will be destroyed or expired.
$my_variable = $_SESSION['abc'];
Before use $_SESSION use session_start(); to create session first

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to understand what it is you want, but I'll take a crack at it.

From what it seems, you simply want to add another condition in your records.php file that checks for a different GET variable.

Add,

```
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
 $otherId = $_GET['id'];
}
```

underneath your first condition.

Comment: I'm sorry my bad english. Thanks but I want to use otherid after selected 'mid' not same time.